# Connecting to Oracle database using cx_Oracle on Python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Am using Debian 5, Python 2.5 with cx_Oracle unicode version installed. I try to connect using the below script but its failing

```
>>> connection = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/XXXXX@local_xe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

I think because the cx_Oracle installed is a unicode version, its asking me to specify the unicode as first parameter. but, Its not taking strings and I don't know what I could supply else?

Comment: try `cx_Oracle.connect(u'hr/XXXXX@local_xe')` ?

Comment: @Sathya: thanks a lot. That solved my problem, do you mind though telling me why we need to put a u before the string? what does that mean?

Comment: @Mo J. I've put an answer explaining why it's needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution was to place the following

```
cx_Oracle.connect(u'hr/XXXXX@local_xe')
```

a u before the string. Not sure why, but that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

You should try

```
cx_Oracle.connect(u'hr/XXXXX@local_xe')
```

Since you have the unicode version of cx_Oracle, it expects the connection string to be a unicode sring (`argument 1 must be unicode, not str`)

Putting a `u''` infront of a string converts it into unicode, and hence it doesn't throw the error.